# why OnpointerClick function is not trigger while using multiple image in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm having two images to move object right and left side while using OnpointerClick function.
Both are working perfectly fine if we try to run individually but somehow its not working simultaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Solve the issue but give up on OnpointerClick and MoveDown function and switch to button instead..But still I can't able figure out why OnPointerClick or moveDown function haven't work if I applied on both images

Comment: You provided no code. We can’t answer that